# Geojson data format and shapes (polygons) in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I have this format of data, in a csv file, it looks like this:

[image]

And when I read with `read.csv2`, it is like this:

```
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.595422739518895, 46.574661252730515], [5.5868864112024, 46.578124834208275], [5.566460487135743, 46.579404434922125], [5.558571581276076, 46.580572027975954], [5.561819437593718, 46.587949918898076], [5.575191603674612, 46.59190224479517], [5.580673541265257, 46.59754467932337], [5.582347290927083, 46.60141691853218], [5.587289521318402, 46.59292683804338], [5.604997996100999, 46.58938109997026], [5.611508140899815, 46.5826199806949], [5.603671590915408, 46.57586134356789], [5.595422739518895, 46.574661252730515]]]}
```

I would like to know how to convert this data (it seems to be a string, after reading it with `read.csv2`) into something that be ploted with leaflet.

Comment: Can you provide the data in an R data frame?  Something reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't know how to provide a data frame. The data first is read in a csv file; then I can see the whole string as one value.

Answer (score 2):

Save your data in a text editor as *.geojson (in the example below test.geojson). Then you can do:

```
library(leaflet)
library(geojsonio)

tst <- geojson_read("/home/ede/test.geojson", what = "sp")

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(data = tst)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer. However, is it possible not to resave the data in a geojson format ? it is read in a csv file. is it possible to convert it into a geojson data ?

Comment: See `geojsonio::geojson_write`

Comment: can you provide the data somewhere? It is really not easy to know what you are after without having access to the original data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to import the JSON data as a data frame is to use the jsonlite package:

```
library(jsonlite)
geojson  <- '{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.595422739518895, 46.574661252730515], [5.5868864112024, 46.578124834208275], [5.566460487135743, 46.579404434922125], [5.558571581276076, 46.580572027975954], [5.561819437593718, 46.587949918898076], [5.575191603674612, 46.59190224479517], [5.580673541265257, 46.59754467932337], [5.582347290927083, 46.60141691853218], [5.587289521318402, 46.59292683804338], [5.604997996100999, 46.58938109997026], [5.611508140899815, 46.5826199806949], [5.603671590915408, 46.57586134356789], [5.595422739518895, 46.574661252730515]]]}'
df <- fromJSON(geojson)
```

NOTE: This is an answer to a question XR SC raised in a comment.